Need regex to match word bounded by / or end of string
I need a regular expression to parse out the companyid and branchid in a url.
The issue is that the branchid may occur at the end of the string or it may occur in the middle of the string. it will always follow /branches.
Here are 2 examples:
http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customers/1128952/branches/83370
http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customers/1128952/branches/83370/validate

where 1128952 is the customerid and 83370 is the branchid
Now I know that
^.*customers/(.*?)/branches/(.*?)$ 

parses out the customerid and branchid for the first example and
^.*customers/(.*?)/branches/(.*?)/.*$

parses out the customerid and branchid for the second example
My problem is I want one regex to parse out the branchid that covers both cases. Can anyone help?

Try: (customers)\/([^\/\s]+)|(branches)\/([^\/\s]+)? You only need the numbers after those branches and customers?

Like this? ^.*customers/(\d+)/branches/(\d+)\b https://regex101.com/r/Ck4UtR/1 or ^\S+/customers/([^\s/]+)/branches/([^\s/]+) https://regex101.com/r/Vmh408/1

funnily enough it works in the regex checker but not when I put it into my java. group2 (the branchid) comes up as null

You can collect into records: record CoBranch(String coId, String branchId){}String u = "http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customers/1128952/branches/83370/validate";Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)/branches/(\\d+)").matcher(u);List<CoBranch> cos = m.results().map(r ->new CoBranch(r.group(1), r.group(2))).toList();

@amadain Which string are you using that gives you a null for group 2?

The matcher was used on /customers/1128952/branches/83370 and with customers/([^/\s]+)|branches/([^/\s]+) I got group1 1128952 and group2 null

I'm using java 11 btw but that doesnt matter

the \b boundary regex worked so I'll use that although I liked the not slash or space solution

based on title, "regex to match word bounded by / or end of string" -- "/(\\w+)(?:/|$)"

after the branchid there may be a / or there may be a end of string

@amadain but this regex customers\/([^\/\s]+)|branches\/([^\/\s]+) has 2 matches instead of 1 due to the alternation | You have a match with group 1 and a match with group 2. See https://regex101.com/r/LuTjjy/1

@amadain Are customers and branches always in the same order?

yes and this worked in my regex checker but when I put it in my code exactly as shown it gave me null. No idea why as the reges looked fine.

just checked and ^.*/customers/(\w+)/branches/(\w+)(?:/|$) worked

so maybe it was the \s in the not statement?

if you can live with a map: Pattern.compile("(?<=(customers|branches))/(\\w+)(?:/|$)").matcher("http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customer s/1128952/branches/83370/validate").results().filter(r -> r.groupCount()>1).collect(toMap(r -> r.group(1), r -> r.group(2))) -- result: {customers=1128952, branches=83370} -- BTW: \w will only match letters and digits (word characters more precisely)

I presume you meant ...customerid and branchi... in the first sentence.

You can use (customers)\\/([^\\/\\s]+)|(branches)\\/([^\\/\\s]+) or simply customers\\/([^\\/\\s]+)|branches\\/([^\\/\\s]+):
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(customers)\\/([^\\/\\s]+)|(branches)\\/([^\\/\\s]+)";
        final String string = "http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customers/1128952/branches/83370\n"
                + "http://localhost:8080/customer-api/customers/1128952/branches/83370/validate";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Capture Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

Prints
Capture Group 1: customers
Capture Group 2: 1128952
Capture Group 3: null
Capture Group 4: null
Capture Group 1: null
Capture Group 2: null
Capture Group 3: branches
Capture Group 4: 83370
Capture Group 1: customers
Capture Group 2: 1128952
Capture Group 3: null
Capture Group 4: null
Capture Group 1: null
Capture Group 2: null
Capture Group 3: branches
Capture Group 4: 83370


Details:

There are four capture groups, which actually you only need two of those. (The other two are just for clarity).

The first two groups are for the customers.

The third and fourth are for the branches.

([^\\/\\s]+) means all chars are allowed, except for \s and /.



If you want to match the digits only in that order, you can use 2 capture groups:
^.*/customers/(\d+)/branches/(\d+)\b

In Java with the doubled escapes:
String regex = "^.*/customers/(\\d+)/branches/(\\d+)\\b";

Regex demo
Or a bit more precise matching the protocol and asserting either a / at the end or the end of the string:
^https?://\S*/customers/(\d+)/branches/(\d+)(?:/|$)

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
https?:// Match the protocol with optional s and then ://
\S* Match optional non whitespace characters
/customers/ Match literally
(\d+)/branches/ Capture 1+ digits in group 1 followed by /branches/
(\d+)(?:/|$) capture 1+ digits in group 2 and match either / or the end of the string

Regex demo
If you want to broaden the match for the id's, instead of \d+ you might also use \w+ to match word characters or [^\s/]+ to match non whitespace characters other than /
